# Add ACF fields to REST API for recursive post

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, advanced-custom-fields

I have custom post type 'Works'. In single work i choose users + several acf fields. In single user i see all works in which this user was chosen.

I installed 'ACF to REST API' and 'ACF to REST API Recursive'.
In response /wp-json/acf/v3/users I have all users and thier works, but single work has only default fields like title, date and etc, without acf fields.
In response /wp-json/acf/v3/works this acf fields exist.

How I can add acf fields in response /wp-json/acf/v3/users?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yesterday, there was a big update for ACF and REST API - try to update to the newest version of the plugin - Read about the new REST support here : https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/blog/acf-5-11-release-rest-api/

Comment: Basically, you now have a setting under each group, called "Show in REST API"

Comment: oh, and the documentaion is found here : https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/rest-api/